# Replacement capacitor for my ceiling fan. 5μF300v

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

## Problem

I have a ceiling fan that is running slowly. I suspect it's the capacitor at fault. I don't see any bulging, but the fan spins for all three settings of the pull chain switch.

## Diagnosis

I have two more identical fans in other rooms in my house. I swapped out the switch housing assembly (the part with the switches, wires, and capacitor) from one of those, and the fan runs fine.

## Questions

Is there a name for the block capacitor packages that have multiple capacitors inside of them? Some term that I can google?

I have been able to find block capacitors with three 5μF250v capacitors inside ... can I use this, or do I need to replace the 5μF300v capacitor with another 5μF300v capacitor ? I thought the fan is running at 120V, where is the 300V coming from? I don't see any kind of transformer.

If not, where should I look to find a suitable replacements capacitor? I contacted the manufacturer (Hunter), but they were no help. The only offered me a discount on the purchase of a new fan.

[image]

Comment: Look for ceiling fan starter capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why hunter has chosen a 300v for one leg when most other CBB61 5 wires are 250v on all three legs.  Inductive surge/kickback on one speed versus the other two is all I can suspect.
I did notice that for hunter fans they sell a two piece unit for replacement listings.  The photo looks like one cap is 300v value and the other is dual 250v.

[hunter replacement](http://www.ereplacementparts.com/capacitor-p-1404604.html)